# jq: error (at report.json:32): Cannot index string with string "complianceId"

Tags: json, linux, shell, csv, jq

I am trying to parse CSV output from json file through jq.

Json looks like this:

```json
{
    "report": {
        "id": "xxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
        "machineId": "xxx-xxxxx-xxxx",
        "scanDate": "2020-12-03T09:11:28Z",
        "moduleReports": {
            "COMPLIANCE": {
                "complianceCheckVersion": "1.3.1",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "complianceId": "Report_ID1",
                        "title": "Title of Report ID1",
                        "status": "FULFILLED",
                        "requirementSourceType": "ABC"
                    },
                    {
                        "complianceId": "Report_ID2",
                        "title": "Title of Report ID2",
                        "status": "FULFILLED",
                        "requirementSourceType": "ABC"
                    },
                    {
                        "complianceId": "Report_ID3",
                        "title": "Title of Report ID3",
                        "status": "FULFILLED",
                        "requirementSourceType": "DEF"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to parse so only results with **key** *requirementSourceType* and **value** is only *ABC*. *DEF* should be filtered out.

With filtering there is not a problem, currently it is done with this command:

```sh
jq -r '.report | .moduleReports | .COMPLIANCE | .items[] | select(.requirementSourceType=="CIS")' report.json
```

But, when I am trying to do an unique columns for CSV report, output with following command:

```sh
jq -r '.report | .moduleReports | .COMPLIANCE | .items[] | select(.requirementSourceType=="CIS") | map({complianceId, title, status}) | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' report.json
```

... I am getting this error:

> jq: error (at report.json:32): Cannot index string with string "complianceId"

Is there any way to fix this error please?

I've tried to research such a solution, but wasn't able to find simmilar case.

Thank you.

### **EDIT**

Expected CSV output:

```
"complianceId","status","title"
"Report_ID1","FULFILLED","Title of Report ID1"
"Report_ID2","FULFILLED","Title of Report ID2"
"Report_ID3","FULFILLED","Title of Report ID3"
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Post updated with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what output you expect. Does this work for you?

```
jq -r '[
    .report.moduleReports.COMPLIANCE.items[]
    | select(.requirementSourceType=="CIS")
    | [.complianceId, .title, .status]
] | unique | .[] | @csv' report.json
```

Comment: Post updated. That works except I miss the top line with specification of columns. Like ```"complianceId","status","title"``` on first line and rest on next lines. Thank you.

Comment: Figured it out. Here is correct format: ```jq -r '[ .report.moduleReports.COMPLIANCE.items[] | select(.requirementSourceType=="CIS") | ["ComplianceID","Status","Title"], [.complianceId, .status, .title] ] | unique | .[] | @csv' report.json```. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BlažejFarkaš - You don't want to include the header line in the array presented to `unique`, which involves a sort.  You can simply use the template:  `HEADERARRAY, (....) | @csv`